# What is this piece of an awk-script doing?

Tags: awk

I'm trying to convert this awkscript into python, and theres this piece with syntax I'm unfamiliar with. I know the piece after the else statement is setting up space padding for outputting to the file but the if/else is confusing me.

```
if (substr($36,1,1) ~ /^[0-9]+$/) {
   C = $36;
   CLen = length($36);
 } 
 else {
   C = substr($36,2);
   CLen = length(C);
 }
 CPad  = 6 - CLen;
 for (i = 1; i <= CPad; ++i) {
     C = C " "
 }
```

Comment: check what does `substr` do in awk, rest is fairly common with other languages.

Comment: The first line says "If the first character of field 36 consists only of digits". The final loop is adding spaces to the end of C to pad the output. Note that awk indices start at 1, not 0.

Comment: I would use AWK's `sprintf` instead of a loop to create a pad.

Comment: Per [How to handle "Explain how ${this code dump} works" questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions) on [meta], questions of this type are innately too broad to be on-topic, unless they eliminate everything but a **very** specific and narrow language-level question.

Comment: ...similarly, a good question title doesn't refer to "this piece of code" or "this awk script", but references something specific enough that other people with the same problem will know if the question and its answers are likely to help them from reading the title alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `#` explanations in code.

```
if (substr($36,1,1) ~ /^[0-9]+$/) {
   # substr($36,1,1) => first char in input field #36
   # ~ => is RegExp match to
   # /^[0-9]+$/ => RegExp of : string consisting of 1 or more digits
   C = $36; # Copy whole input field #36 to variable C
   CLen = length($36); # Assign lenght of input field #36 to variable CLen
 } 
 else { 
   C = substr($36,2); # Copy input field #36 from second char to end, into to variable C
   CLen = length(C); # Assign length of variable C to variable CLen
 }
 CPad  = 6 - CLen; # Compute CPad
 for (i = 1; i <= CPad; ++i) {
     C = C " " # pad CPad spaces to C right side. 
 }
```

Good luck.

Comment: See [How to handle "Explain how ${this code dump} works" questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions) on [meta], and the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer); it's generally appropriate to ask the OP to narrow a question of this type before answering it, to narrow the question enough that people other than the person who asked it will be able to learn from the answer.

Comment: ("What does `~` mean in an awk condition?", for example, is something someone might see in a question title in their search result listing and say "hey, that's what I need to know!"; but "this piece of awk script" will refer to something different for everyone, so it's useful to nobody else... or, at least, impossible to find by the people who are actually searching for it).

Answer (score 0):

note that this is a useless combination of substr and regex match

```
substr($36,1,1) ~ /^[0-9]+$/
```

it's equivalent to `$36 ~ /^[0-9]/`

right padding to 6 chars can be done with this as well

```
c=sprintf("%-6s",c)
```

In summary, delete the first char if it's a digit, right pad to 6 chars long. Perhaps easier this way...

```
sub(/^[0-9]/,"",$36); c=sprintf("%-6s",$36)
```